# Pdf File corrupted when downloading it using apache http client

Tags: java, apache, pdf, download, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to automate downloading a pdf file over a network. When it is opened manually in a browser it was in a PDF Acrobat format. I can download by clicking the print or save option in the page. 
I have written a `Downloader.java` attached. It's working fine with a [sample PDF available in the network](http://www.mothergoosecaboose.com/newstuff/nrb/NURSERYRHYMEBOOK.pdf).
But when I try to download file from the following URL

```
URL("https://myapplication.com//mod.dll?tenant=tnt_name&b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=%2Fcontent%2Ffolder%5B%40name%3D%27basic+reports_101%27%5D+%2Freport%5B%40name%3D%27KJL99.xml%27%5D&ui.name=KJL99.xml&**run.outputFormat**=PDF&run.prompt=false&SESSkIONID=6121&p_R5_FRONTPG=-&JOB=1122&run.print=falseSaved");
```

it's downloaded successfully, but can't be opened:

> Acrobat could not open '[name of file]' because it is either not a
>   supported file type or because the file has been damaged

Tried a few solutions from the several forums but they didn't fix it. Can I get some help please?
Below is  the code snippet of `Downloader.java`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;enter code here
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.LaxRedirectStrategy;


public class Downloader {

    public File download(URL url, File dstFile) {

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()) // adds HTTP REDIRECT support to GET and POST methods 
                    .build();
        try {
            HttpPost get = new HttpPost(url.toURI()); // we're using GET but it could be via POST as well
            File downloaded = httpclient.execute(get, new FileDownloadResponseHandler(dstFile));
            return downloaded;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(httpclient);
        }
    }

    static class FileDownloadResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<File> {

        private final File target;

        public FileDownloadResponseHandler(File target) {
            this.target = target;
        }

        @Override
        public File handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            InputStream source = response.getEntity().getContent();
            FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(source, this.target);
            return this.target;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: that preview window exists for a reason. You want us to spend our time to help you - so you want to make that as simple as possible. Starting with posting a completely formatted/indented question ...

Comment: Have you compared the downloaded file with the original one? Is the size correct? What does a binary comparison show?

Comment: Are you able to open that file if you download it manually?

Comment: that been said, you do a POST but use URL-encoded parameters. That is not accepted by every server. And one of those parameters is a session ID. Are you sure that session is still considered active?

Comment: @mkl .. Yes for a sample pdf of rhymes file, I have downloaded manually and through code. It is the same w.r.t size. I didn't compare in binary. Regarding the session , yes it is active - I make sure it is active all the time.

Comment: @GhostCat - My bad, I have given a try to format it but still ended like this.. :(

Comment: @AlekseiBudiak - Yes , manually I am able to download it and open it properly.

Comment: then please try and compare on a binary level. If there are differences, what kind of differences?  Or share both the working and the broken pdf for us to compare.

Comment: @phalgunamattangi, when you download it manually, you use GET method, I assume. So please try GET in your application too.

Comment: @AlekseiBudiak - Yes , i have used GET method as well. Didn't work.

Comment: @mkl. I shall need quite sometime to launch my app again. Will share the info to you.

Comment: @mkl - Have got both the versions(manual and automated) from my URL. Not sure how to share those with you. But the corrupted one is always 9KB size. The actual (healthy) one's differs with it.

Comment: *"Not sure how to share those with you."* - Usually one makes them available on a file sharing service (e.g. a public googledrive or dropbox share, nothing with ads, please) and posts the URLs here. *"But the corrupted one is always 9KB size."* - You might want to look at it in an editor. Probably the "PDF" actually is a HTML page indicating something went wrong...

Comment: "Probably the "PDF" actually is a HTML page indicating something went wrong..." - That's true. The URL is a IBM Cognos link which opens the file in a PDF format. The content which is corrupted contains HTML code. Finding other options to download in right way. I believe the file share isn't needed now .. :)

Comment: @mkl - Have tried some options like http://pdfcrowd.com/web-html-to-pdf-java/ .. But it is opening a new session window which asks for authentication of my app and that screen is converting into PDF. Seems like bit hectic task to automate the html content to PDF. I shall take a call from here. Thanks for your help ! :) ..

Comment: Figured out the way of doing it. Disable the Acrobat format Add-on of you Browser , which will automatically download the file in IE cache and opens with Acrobat reader. Click on its properties to view its path in the system.